# Cargar Select a partir de otro

Tags: php, html, ajax

Estoy tratando de realizar este ejercicio:
https://jonathanmelgoza.com/blog/select-dinamico-de-estados-y-municipios-con-jquery-y-php/

Sin embargo no me carga nada en los Selects, estoy trabajando con Bootstrap 4, la función la tengo integrada en una carpeta de nombre scripts js, la función que muestra ahí no la tengo en el index.html y el php también lo tengo en una carpeta php.

Si me pudieran apoya, se los agradecería, haber que estoy haciendo mal.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Obtener estados
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../php/procesar-estados.php",
    data: { estados : "Mexico" } 
    }).done(function(data){
    $("#jmr_contacto_estado").html(data);
    });
    // Obtener municipios
    $("#jmr_contacto_estado").change(function(){
    var estado = $("#jmr_contacto_estado option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../php/procesar-estados.php",
    data: { municipios : estado } 
    }).done(function(data){
    $("#jmr_contacto_municipio").html(data);
    });
    });
    });
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="estado">ESTADO</label>
                    <select id="jmr_contacto_estado" class="form-control">
                      <option>Selecciona tu estado</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="estado">MUNICIPIO</label>
                    <select id="jmr_contacto_municipio" class="form-control">
                      <option>Selecciona tu municipio</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
```

Comment: tu problema está aquí `$("#jmr_contacto_municipio").html(data);` Para que funcione data ha debido ser preparado en el servidor como un bloque html bien estructurado y seguramente viene como una cadena con formato json de modo que al no aplicarle un tratamiento adecuado si muestras algo es "basura"

Comment: ¿Y que es lo que se tendría que hacer?

Comment: Primero muestra como preparas la respuesta del lado del servidor. Así podemos saber qué hacer con ella. O, cómo mejorarla para que pase limpia en .html(data)

Answer (score 0):

```
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="estado">ESTADO</label>
                    <select id="jmr_contacto_estado" class="form-control" onchange="getmuni();">
                      <option  value="<?php echo $fila['id_depto']">codigo php que genere los estados</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="estado">MUNICIPIO</label>
                    <select id="jmr_contacto_municipio" class="form-control">
                      
                    </select>
                  </div>
```

Basicamente puedes poner el codigo dentro de una funcion y asi no sobrecargas el document.ready, luego fuera del onready pones la funcion para ser llamada por el evento onchange de tu select principial (departamento/estado), segun el que seleccione en el select de municipios cargaran los municipios que pertenecen al mismo, los resultados la de la funcion municipio se imprimen en formato json para que la funcion los lea correctamente.

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
// 
                });
function getmuni(){
                // Obtener estados
        const parametros = {
          "id_depto" : $("#jmr_contacto_estado").val(),
          };
               $.ajax({
         async: false,
       data: parametros, 
       url: '../php/procesar-estados.php', 
       type: 'post',
       beforeSend: function(){
        // quitarCargador();
       }, 
       success: function(response){
             
                const municipio = JSON.parse(response);
                let template = '';
                municipio.forEach(municipio => {
                  template += `
                                <option value="${municipio.id_municipio}">${municipio.municipio}</option>
                        ` 
                });
                $('#jmr_contacto_municipio').html(template);
             
       }
    });
}
</script>
```